# or match can be device

Tags: articles

> As nouns the difference between match and bout is that match is (sports) sporting event such as a boxing meet, a baseball game, or **a cricket match or match can be device** made of wood or paper, at the tip coated with chemicals that ignite with the friction of being dragged (struck) against a rough dry surface while bout is a period of something, usually painful or unpleasant.
> [Source:Wikidiff](https://wikidiff.com/match/bout)

I don't understand "match can be device" - why not "match can be a device"? Is the latter ungrammatical?

Comment: The paragraph has several article mistakes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking us to analyse poorly-written (software-generated?) text that hasn't been *remotely* proof-read by a competent Anglophone human.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikidiff is a automatic system. It tries to take sources (perhaps wikipeida?) and use AI to write a comparative paragraph.  Here it has failed to produce good English. And it has failed to produce a useful comparison.

It has found that "match" can mean "a sporting event" and gives some examples.  It then says "match" can also mean a "device made of wood or paper, at the tip coated with chemicals that ignite with the friction of being dragged (struck) against a rough dry surface".  The AI has failed to punctuate properly and has made several errors, missing out the word "a".

It then goes on to define the word "bout".

It has failed to write a useful comparison, because it hasn't noticed the similarity in the words. It is just spouting dictionary definitions.  By not focusing on the similarity between the words, it fails to identify the differences that distinguish the words. It has failed to tell you about the difference between "match" and "bout".

Wikidiff is a pretty poor service, I've rarely seen anything useful in the automated answers it gives.

Answer (score 2):

To be brief, yes, it should be **match can be *a* device**.

But as Lambie says, the passage is full of errors and is not an example of good, clear, or even grammatical English.

Answer (score 1):

That should indeed be "a match can be a device made of wood or paper"  The articles are needed in this construction.